# I need to redirect the page to generated image URL

Tags: php, redirect

mypage.php generate a different image each time it loaded. The page source:
`<img src='//mysite.com/000avvykhwfsh245vy4cdo3z.gif' height='0' width='0'>`
I need to redirect the page to generated image URL. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The question is very vague so I might get you completely wrong, if you want to redirect to a page like this, try:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=<?=$sitelink?>/" />
```

or

```
header("Location: '$sitelink'");
```

Comment: Thank you for the responce, I try to afrticulate differently.
The page must redirect to xxx.gif. But my page generate every time a new image: xxx.gif, yyy.gif, zzz.gif... And it must go to the new URL each time

Comment: So all you want is a script that generates a random for/page

Comment: Show the script please